# Unable to use jsonpath_rw_ext with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, jsonpath

These are the steps I am following:

1. `mkdir spark_lib; cd spark_lib`
2. `pip install jsonpath_rw_ext==1.1.3 -t .`
3. `zip -r9 ../spark_lib.zip *`
4. Initialize spark context variable `sc`
5. `sc.addPyFile('spark_lib.zip')`
6. ```
   def f(x):
       import jsonpath_rw_ext
       return jsonpath_rw_ext.match('$.a.b', x)                
   sc.parallelize([{"a":{"b":10}}]).map(f).collect()
   ```

This gives me a pbr versioning error

```
File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
   vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "<ipython-input-11-2619fc011e24>", line 6, in f
File "./spark_lib.zip/jsonpath_rw_ext/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
File "./spark_lib.zip/pbr/version.py", line 467, in version_string
  return self.semantic_version().brief_string()
File "./spark_lib.zip/pbr/version.py", line 462, in semantic_version
  self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
File "./spark_lib.zip/pbr/version.py", line 449, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources 
  result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)
File "./spark_lib.zip/pbr/packaging.py", line 824, in get_version
  name=package_name))

Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, 
or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that 
there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg 
and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. 
Project name jsonpath_rw_ext was given, but was not able to be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through another similar bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-swiftclient/+bug/1379579, found out that pbr needs updated setuptools.

I included setuptools in my pip installation command and everything worked fine.

2. `pip install jsonpath_rw_ext setuptools -t .`